Error in compiling with Class defined in Header File
I was implementing vec3 class inside my vec3.h header file and using it in another color.h file
but I am getting errors compiling my file which I can't make any sense of.
first_image.cpp
#include "vec3.h"
#include "color.h"

#include<iostream>
#define max_val 255
#define length 255
int main()
{
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(0), std::cin.tie(0);
    int image_width = length;
    int image_height = length;
    std::cout <<"P3\n" << image_width <<' '<<image_height<<"\n" << max_val<<"\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < image_height; ++i)
    {       
        for(int j = 0; j < image_width; ++j)
        {
           auto pixel_color = color(double(i)/(image_width - 1), double(j)/(image_height-1), 0);
           write_color(std::cout,pixel_color);
        }
    }
    std::clog << "\rDone                                          \n";
}

vec3.h
#ifndef VEC3_H
#define VEC3_H
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cassert>

using std:: sqrt;
class vec3{
    public : 
    double e[3];
    vec3(): e{0,0,0}{}
    vec3(double d1, double d2, double d3): e{d1,d2,d3}{}

    double x() const {return e[0];} //return x coordinate
    double y() const {return e[1];} //return y coordinate
    double z() const {return e[2];} //return z coordinate

    vec3 operator -() const {return vec3( -e[0], -e[1], e[2]);} // return negative of vector
    double operator[](int i) const {assert(i < 3); return e[i];}
    double &operator[](int i) {assert(i < 3); return e[i];}

    vec3& operator += (const vec3 &v )// adding two vec3
    {
        e[0] += v.e[0];
        e[1] += v.e[1];
        e[2] += v.e[2];
        return *this;
    }
    vec3& operator *= (const double t )// multiplying by a double
    {
        e[0] *= t;
        e[1] *= t;
        e[2] *= t;
        return *this;
    }
    vec3 &operator /=(const double t)//dividing by a double
    {
        return *this *= 1/t;
    }
    double length_squared() const
    {
        return e[0]*e[0] + e[1]*e[1] + e[2]*e[2];
    }
    double length() const //length of vector
    {
        return sqrt(length_squared());
    }
};

using point3 = vec3;

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&out ,const vec3& v)
{out << v.e[0]<<' '<<v.e[1]<<' '<<v.e[2];return out;}

inline vec3 operator+(const vec3& v, const vec3& u)// addition
{
    return vec3({v.e[0] + u.e[0], v.e[1] + u.e[1], v.e[2] + u.e[2]});
}

inline vec3 operator-(const vec3& v, const vec3& u)// difference
{
    return vec3({v.e[0] - u.e[0], v.e[1] - u.e[1], v.e[2] - u.e[2]});
}

inline vec3 operator*(const vec3& v, const vec3& u)
{
    return vec3({v.e[0] * u.e[0], v.e[1] * u.e[1], v.e[2] * u.e[2]});
}

inline vec3 operator*(double t, const vec3& u) // multiplication by scalar
{
    return vec3({t * u.e[0], t * u.e[1], t * u.e[2]});
}

inline vec3 operator*( const vec3& u ,double t) // multiplication by scalar
{
    return t * u;
}

inline vec3 operator/( const vec3& u ,double t) // divide by scalar
{
    return (1/t) * u;
}

inline double dot(const vec3 &v, const vec3 &u) // dot product 
{
    return v.e[0]*u.e[0] + v.e[1]*u.e[1] + v.e[2]*u.e[2];
}

inline vec3 cross(const vec3 &v, const vec3 &u) //cross product (vector perpendicular to v and u)
{
    return vec3({   v.e[1]*u.e[2] - v.e[2]*u.e[0], 
                    v.e[2]*u.e[0] - v.e[0]*u.e[2],
                    v.e[0]*u.e[1] - v.e[1]*u.e[0]
                });
}
inline vec3 unit_vector(const vec3 &v) // normalize
{
    return v / v.length();
}

#endif

color.h
#ifndef COLOR_H
#define COLOR_H

#include "vec3.h" // we will use our vec3 class to represent color
#include<iostream>

using color = vec3;
void write_color (std::ostream& out, const color& pixel)
{
    auto r = pixel.x();
    auto g = pixel.y();
    auto b = pixel.z();
    //convert to [0,255] range
    int rbyte = int(255.999 * r);
    int gbyte = int(255.999 * g);
    int bbyte = int(255.999 * b);
    out <<rbyte << ' '<<gbyte <<' '<<bbyte<<'\n';
    
}

#endif

when I run g++ -o first_image first_image.cpp
I get following errors
In file included from first_image.cpp:1:
./vec3.h:11:21: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
    vec3(): e{0,0,0}{}
                    ^
./vec3.h:11:14: error: expected '('
    vec3(): e{0,0,0}{}
             ^
./vec3.h:11:20: error: expected ';' after expression
    vec3(): e{0,0,0}{}
                   ^
                   ;
./vec3.h:11:15: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
    vec3(): e{0,0,0}{}
              ^
./vec3.h:50:16: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
using point3 = vec3;
               ^
./vec3.h:57:17: error: expected expression
    return vec3({v.e[0] + u.e[0], v.e[1] + u.e[1], v.e[2] + u.e[2]});
                ^
./vec3.h:62:17: error: expected expression
    return vec3({v.e[0] - u.e[0], v.e[1] - u.e[1], v.e[2] - u.e[2]});
                ^
./vec3.h:67:17: error: expected expression
    return vec3({v.e[0] * u.e[0], v.e[1] * u.e[1], v.e[2] * u.e[2]});
                ^
./vec3.h:72:17: error: expected expression
    return vec3({t * u.e[0], t * u.e[1], t * u.e[2]});
                ^
./vec3.h:92:17: error: expected expression
    return vec3({   v.e[1]*u.e[2] - v.e[2]*u.e[0], 
                ^
./vec3.h:99:18: error: no member named 'length' in 'vec3'
    return v / v.length();
               ~ ^
In file included from first_image.cpp:2:
./color.h:7:15: warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
using color = vec3;
              ^
./color.h:10:5: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    auto r = pixel.x();
    ^
./color.h:10:20: error: no member named 'x' in 'vec3'
    auto r = pixel.x();
             ~~~~~ ^
./color.h:11:5: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    auto g = pixel.y();
    ^
./color.h:11:20: error: no member named 'y' in 'vec3'
    auto g = pixel.y();
             ~~~~~ ^
./color.h:12:5: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    auto b = pixel.z();
    ^
./color.h:12:20: error: no member named 'z' in 'vec3'
    auto b = pixel.z();
             ~~~~~ ^
first_image.cpp:17:12: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
           auto pixel_color = color(double(i)/(image_width - 1), double(j)/(image_height-1), 0);
           ^
first_image.cpp:17:31: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'color' (aka 'vec3')
           auto pixel_color = color(double(i)/(image_width - 1), double(j)/(image_height-1), 0);
                              ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./vec3.h:8:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 3 were provided
class vec3{
      ^
./vec3.h:11:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 3 were provided
    vec3(): e{0,0,0}{}

I don't really know why such error occurs as far as I know definition of my vec3 class is correct.

One hint is here. warning: alias declarations are a C++11 extension which means that you use a C++ standard earlier than C++11. That happens on a Mac, if you don't select a standard. Instead, try g++ -std=c++17 ...

In color.h void write_color (std::ostream& out, const color& pixel) should be inline void write_color (std::ostream& out, const color& pixel). You got this right in vec3.h but not color.h

You pick the tag [tag:C++17] but you don't set it to g++.
